# Schedule Checker

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

How could I reduce this schedule checker? There are too many conditions.

This code is supposed to make sure we're not booking events for employees that are already booked in a specified timeframe.

```
for i in range(len(employeesChosen)):
    info = get_employee_info(employeesChosen[i])
    event_done = False
    if employeesChosen[i] not in currentEmployees and check_employee_availability(service,employeesChosen[i],currentStart,currentEnd,currentStart,calendarEnd):
        event_done = True
    else:
        for event in events:
            if employeesChosen[i] == event['summary']:

                if str2datetime(currentStart) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False
                    break

                elif str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False
                    break

                elif str2datetime(currentStart) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False
                    break

                elif str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                    event_done = False
                    break

                elif str2datetime(currentStart) < str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):  #rdv avant un qui est deja set
                    event_info = {'location': get_company_location(event['description']),'datetime': event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    start_first_event = {'location': get_company_location(event['description']),'datetime': event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    event_fabricant_info = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant),'datetime': currentStart}
                    end_second_event = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant),'datetime': currentEnd}
                    if check_event_possibility_if_before(event_info, event_fabricant_info, end_second_event, start_first_event, info[0]):
                        event_done = True
                    else:
                        event_done = False


                elif str2datetime(currentStart) > str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) or str2datetime(currentEnd): #rdv apres un qui est deja set
                    event_info={'location': get_company_location(event['description']), 'datetime': event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    start_first_event ={'location': get_company_location(event['description']), 'datetime': event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]}
                    event_fabricant_info = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant), 'datetime': currentStart}
                    end_second_event = {'location': get_company_location(event_fabricant), 'datetime': currentEnd}
                    if check_event_possibility(event_info, event_fabricant_info, end_second_event,start_first_event, info[0]):
                        event_done=True
                    else:
                        event_done=False

                else: event_done = False
```

Answer (score 3):

### Specific suggestions

1. You can pull out variables for the several repeated calls (such as `str2datetime(currentStart)`) to massively simplify the code.
2. The idiomatic way to write

   ```
   for counter in range(len(foos)):
       foo = foos[counter]
   ```

   is

   ```
   for foo in foos:
   ```

### Tool support

1. Use a formatter like [Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) to format the code to be more idiomatic.
2. Use a linter like [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) to recommend further changes like using `snake_case` variable names.

Answer (score 1):

After introducing the variables `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` as @l0b0 suggested, your code becomes much clearer and more readable. It seems like your first 4 if/elif statements will always be True so the later statements will never be reached.

```
start_datetime = str2datetime(currentStart)
end_datetime = str2datetime(currentEnd)
event_start = str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0])
event_end = str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0])

if start_datetime >= event_start and end_datetime  <= event_end:
                                event_done = False
                                break

elif start_datetime  <= event_start  and end_datetime  <= event_end:
                                event_done = False
                                break

elif start_datetime  >= event_start and end_datetime  >= event_end :
                                event_done = False
                                break

elif start_datetime  <= event_start and end_datetime >= event_end:
                                event_done = False
                                break
```

I suppose that's not what you actually meant to do so you should change that first. If this is the behaviour you want; you can change this entire part to

```
event_done = False
```

and delete all conditions after this.

Something else, try to make your code [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant. These are guidelines for how to format your code like making your lines max 79 characters long.